# Is there a way to edit the ssh config to echo a custom text for each hostname?

Tags: ssh

I have an ssh config file with several host and each host has some port forwarding preconfigured

```
Host host
  HostName host.server.com
  User user
  LocalForward 1234 localhost:9911
  LocalForward 5678 localhost:9922
```

Is there a simple way to display a text like

```
Service 1 (port: 9911) forwarded to port: 1234
Service 2 (port: 9922) forwarded to port: 5678
```

upon login?

Comment: don't you mean `Service 1 (port: 1234) forwarded to port: 9911` ?

Answer (score 1):

Awk solution:

```
awk '/LocalForward/ 
{ count++;
  split($3,arr,":");
  printf "Service %i ( port: "arr[2]") forwarded to port : "$2"\n",count 
}' ssh_config
```

Pattern match for any LocalForward lines and then increment a variable count. Split the third space delimited field on the line using : putting the results in an array (arr). Print the text required extracting the second element in the arr array along with the second space delimited piece of data on the line.

Comment: No that's not right, 'cos first of all (minor problem first), that would be displaying before even attempting to log in. whereas he said upon login. so it's not quite what he wants, though that might not be an issue. But Second issue, that's going to cover all lines matching the pattern LocalForward, but he won't want that, because if you know a bit about SSH, he might have another Host block, And you should only be matching for the Host block specified in his ssh command.